# npm install Expo cli, stops at extraxt: rxjs

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, rxjs5

I am trying to install Expo for React Native using `npm install -g expo-cli`. But the installation halts or indefinite time at `extract:rxjs: still extract rxjs@5.5.2 extracted to c:/...`

Now,
1. I used administrator privilege for cli
2. I tried this for 3 time in a day, but each time the system halts in same place

Node -v 10.15.3

npm -v 6.4.1

windows 7

How can i make this done? Any guess?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after 2 days.

Still i don't know why it stops in my working PC(**PC1**). So i decided to install in another PC (**PC2**), both using windows7, where it get installed in no time.

Next, i just copied the downloaded folder npm from PC2 to PC1, and it works.
Path of npm folder: Users >> username >> AppData >> Roaming >> npm (i tried global installation in both PC)

So, npm just downloads the required resources and stores in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the steps**

- First, run `npm cache verify`.
- Open Windows PowerShell as administrator and run `npm install expo-cli --global --no-optional` command.